# Discord.py client.wait_for() sends multiple messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with rewrite, but when my command runs, SOMETIMES sends all the messages at once, sometimes works well. Anyone knows why? I'm struggling with this a long time

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!order"):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("in game name")
        in_game_name = await client.wait_for('message', check=None)

        await channel.send("in game ID")
        in_game_ID = await client.wait_for('message', check=None)

        await channel.send("cargo type")
        cargo_type = await client.wait_for('message', check=None)

        await channel.send("cargo limit")
        cargo_limit = await client.wait_for('message', check=None)

        await channel.send("storage")
        storage = await client.wait_for('message', check=None)

        await channel.send("priority")
        priority = await client.wait_for('message', check=None)
```

Comment: You should add a check so that the bot will not accept its own messages as a response.

Comment: If I add it, It must be a specific response from the user to the send the next message, and I need a random one like "haha", "haasdasdksdjgf"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a check function that only checks that the message is in the correct channel and was not sent by the bot:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user
    if message.content.startswith("!order"):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("in game name")
        in_game_name = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        ...
```

Comment: thank you, I changed the variable channel to "channel = message.author", but now, it doesn't work when the user types the command in the chat, the bot dm's him, but the user needs to type the command one more time in the dm's for it to work, how can I avoid that?

Comment: The check checks against `message.channel`.  You would want it to check against `message.author.dm_channel` instead